# Webpack bundle with 'jsonpath' dependency

Tags: webpack, bundle, jsonpath

We use a webpack to bundle our lambdas before we deploy them.
Ever since we added code that has a dependency on "jsonpath," the code fails immediately with the following.

> TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined
> at isFileType (fs.js:163:16)
> at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:346:16)
> at Object.28729 (/.../bundle.js:2:4710658)

I am pretty new to Webpack, so I am unsure where to go with this. Code works fine, but it's not bundled. Also, I have tried different versions of Webpack. Can someone suggest how to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error within [Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/), which is an alternative to [AWS Lambdas](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/).

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './node_modules/jsonpath/include/module.js'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:476:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:377:35)
```

Since the error message was more expressive, it turned out, that the `jsonpath` package expects several files next to its location, since it uses [`require.resolve`](https://github.com/dchester/jsonpath/search?q=require.resolve).

You can fix the issue by copying the required files next to your function, e.g. using `copy-webpack-plugin` in your `webpack.config.js`.

```
plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
        patterns: [
            // required node_modules for jsonpath (see https://github.com/dchester/jsonpath/search?q=require.resolve)
            {from: 'node_modules/jsonpath/include', to: 'node_modules/jsonpath/include'},
            {from: 'node_modules/esprima', to: 'node_modules/esprima'},
        ]
    })
],
```